# ¿Cómo usar la librería ctime para adelantar la hora y fecha?

Tags: c++, date, class, herencia

> Diseñe una clase `RELOJ` con atributos Hora, Minuto y Segundo, y métodos para imprimir la hora y borrarla. Debe asimismo contener un atributo Alarma (booleano) iniciado en False. El constructor por defecto de `RELOJ` debe inicializar el tiempo a la hora actual (use la librería `ctime`) y la alarma a cero.
>
> La clase `RELOJ` debe contener además métodos para: activar la alarma, que defina el booleano Alarma a True y a una hora determinada, apagar la alarma, y mostrar la alarma, es decir, imprimir los datos de la alarma. El código debe ejecutar el siguiente procedimiento :
>
> - Inicializar un objeto de clase RELOJ con la hora actual y la alarma apagada.
> - Activar la alarma si la hora es mayor que las 8:00 am y ponerla a las 8 am del día siguiente (o del mismo día si ya es mas de medianoche).
> - imprimir la hora actual y los datos de la alarma.
> - adelantar la hora a las 8 am del día siguiente, apagar la alarma e imprimir la hora.

Utilice la librería `ctime` adecuadamente para implementar los métodos del problema.

Hasta el momento he implementado la clase reloj de la siguiente manera:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;

class CReloj {
private:
    int hora;
    int minutos;
    int segundos;
public:
    CReloj(){}
    void setHora(){
        time_t now = time(0);
        tm *time = localtime(&now);
        int t = time->tm_hour;
        hora = t;
    }
    void setMinutos(){
        time_t now = time(0);
        tm *time = localtime(&now);
        int m = time->tm_min;
        minutos = m;
    }
    void setSegundos(){
        time_t now = time(0);
        tm *time = localtime(&now);
        int s = time->tm_sec;
        segundos = s;
    }

    int getHora(){return hora;}
    int getMinutos(){return minutos;}
    int getSegundos(){return segundos;}

    void imprimirHora(){
        cout << getHora() << ":" << getMinutos() << ":" << getSegundos() << "\n";
    }
};

int main(){
    CReloj A;
    A.setHora();
    A.setMinutos();
    A.setSegundos();
    A.imprimirHora();
    return 0;
}
```

Sin embargo, ¿cómo debo declarar la clase CAlarma como clase hija de CReloj y además adelantar la hora, activar y desactivar la alarma?

Comment: ¿Por qué hablas de una clase `CAlarma` si en el enunciado dice "*contener un atributo Alarma (booleano)*"?

Comment: Cierto, tienes razón. En todo caso mi duda sigue siendo cómo implementar los métodos respecto a la alarma.